# Authenticate to Sharepoint Online/Office 365 with cURL

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

I am currently trying to develop a PHP application that checks whether or not a folder exists in a SharePoint directory. While I have managed to submit the right REST requests when logged in inside the browser, my problem is authenticating using URL.

There are a two requirements to this:

1. I do not have Admin access to our SharePoint subscription so I cannot register apps
2. I can only use an existing user account and authenticate with email/password.

I have found several tutorials and even thybag's PHP library for SharePoint.
None of these things work and I assume there has been a change in the authentication method. I am still able to get the Binary Token from Microsoft's Server but sending it to the SharePoint server doesn't work.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [phpSPO](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) and [PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API/blob/develop/src/Thybag/Auth/SharePointOnlineAuth.php) (see [SharePointOnlineAuth.php](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API/blob/develop/src/Thybag/Auth/SharePointOnlineAuth.php)) libraries support *claims-based authentication for SharePoint Online*.

The following diagram illustrates how active authentication to SharePoint Online (SPO) is performed

[image]

### [phpSPO](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO)

```
client.signIn (username, password)
```

The signin method performs a claims-based authentication:

- build a SAML request (using SAML.xml template included in module)
- submit a SAML token request to Microsoft Online Security Token
  Service
- receive a signed security token
- POST the token to SharePoint Online
- receive `FedAuth` and `rtFa` authentication cookies
- store the cookies in client for use in subsequent requests

**Example**

```
try {
    $client = new SPOClient($url);
    $client->signIn($username,$password);
    echo 'You have authenticated successfully\n';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

> Disclaimer: i'm the author of [phpSPO library](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library

https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

```
<?php

require_once 'SPOClient.php';

$username = 'username@domain.onmicrosoft.com';
$password = 'password';
$url = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/";

$client = new SPOClient($url);
$client->signIn($username,$password);

?>
```

Comment: This library does essentially the same thing as Thybag's library. My problem is the authentication URL (/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0). This always returns a redirect to the new https://login.microsoftonline.com.
This doesn't seem to support authentication via BinaryToken.