# curl request to access file through REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Is there a simple way to use a [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) request to the REST API to access a file on my Sharepoint account? For example

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <some-key-here>" https://mysharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists
```

I have read all the documentation about [authentication and authorization for apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142384.aspx), but in this case I don't have an "application" that I can register. I simply need an API key of some kind to use in REST requests. How can I use the REST API in this way?

Answer (score 3):

The first you have to get auth cookies. 
The auth process you can see at the figure 
[image]

I don't think exists ready to use solution for this, but the following links may be useful for you:

- [Using cURL to authenticate with Sharepoint](http://www.redstubble.com/content/using-curl-authenticate-sharepoint)
- [Authenticate to Sharepoint Online/Office 365 with cURL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126409/authenticate-to-sharepoint-online-office-365-with-curl)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately those links both use PHP, which will not work for me. Do you know if there are any solutions like that in Java?

Comment: There is really not so much, but I think you can start from this https://gist.github.com/mirontoli/3702971