# How to upload a file to SharePoint Online from php code

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, php

I state that I am a beginner regarding SharePoint Online. My question is to know if there is a way to upload a (PDF) file to SharePoint Online with php. Basically I own a site in drupal, so I would like to load PDF files through php code so as to integrate it into the site.

I've read this post ([Using Linux Shell scripting to upload a document to SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186740/using-linux-shell-scripting-to-upload-a-document-to-sharepoint)) , but I'm not sure how to use the answers or if they are right for me.

Can someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RESTAPI to upload the file. You should authenticate your client(this case PHP code)

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I am not a PHP guy but I can see there are success stories. Give a try.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005601/how-to-authenticate-with-sharepoint-online-for-a-php-app

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem